# Workaround for jstack -l

Tags: linux, permissions, thread-dump, jstack

I've an java app named `my-app` which is running from specific user `my-app-user` and I want to take thread dumps once in a hour. I found `jstack` which is bundled with JDK and I want to execute it with `-l` flag. But, unfortunately I found that I should run jstack as `my-app-user` user if I want to get my thread dump. The problem is that jstack has root:root ownership and I can't change it. Are there some workaround for this problem? I have no idea how can I resolve this.

Thanks

Comment: Not a real [tag:java] question. Better match for [sf].

Comment: Ye, I think you are right, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$ sudo -u my-app-user jstack -l
```

Reference: http://linux.die.net/man/8/sudo